# Active Object - implementation issues

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to implement [Active Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object).
In all sample implementations, ActivationQueue is synchronizing the access to message queues. i am thinking why it is done within this class.
Why Scheduler is not synchronizing the access to ActivationQueue. It is the only object, who accesses this ActivationQueue object. Synchronization can be very simple here.
Question is - what is the better place for synchronizing access to ActivationQueue - within scheduler or ActivationQueue itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are right that in the original approach by Lavender and Schmidt only the scheduler accesses the queue, it is a better choise to implement the synchronization in the queue.
There are two reasons:

1. It is a clearer design to synchonize the protected object, since the problem (possible inconsistency) and its soulution (synchronization) are better bound.
2. There are implementations for AO, where requests are directly scheduled to the queue (by external entities), and the scheduler "only" decides on reordering.

Answer (score 0):

In the QP/C++ active object framework (http://www.state-machine.com/qp) this is done even simpler. Each active object owns its own event queue and this queue blocks the active object thread as long as it is empty. When an event is posted to the active object queue, the queue unblocks. If several active objects are unblocked that way, the scheduling is left to the underlying multitasking kernel. This means that active objects can freely preempt each other, depending on the priorities assigned to the threads of active objects. This approach is clean, simple, and exactly how UML specification recommends handling the RTC (run-to-completion) processing within active objects. For specific implementations see the P-thread version, http://www.state-machine.com/linux/ or Win32 version at http://www.state-machine.com/win32 ).